# Laravel PDF Insert WEBP Image

Tags: laravel, pdf, dompdf

How to render webp image at dompdf??

Below are my view code :

```
<body>
    <img src="4.webp">
    <br>
    <img src="1.png">
</body>
```

Below are my controller code :

```
$pdf = PDF::loadView( 'admin.registrations.index' );
return $pdf->stream( 'image.pdf' );
```

The png image is showed, but the webp doesn't.

I try to open the page via blade view :

```
return view( 'admin.registrations.index' );
```

Both image showed..

How to enable webp at dompdf??

Comment: 1. get the contents of the file. 2. base 64 encode it. 3. serve the base 64 decoded image

Comment: tried it but still not work, because event i encoded it with base64, the type of base64 still webp : data:image/webp;base64........ Try encode the png it's work.. the problem is the file type

Answer (score 0):

Dompdf does not currently (up to and including 0.7.0) support WebP. Supported image types are:

- BMP
- GIF
- JPEG
- PNG
- SVG (partial, using php-svg-lib)

Recommend that you submit an enhancement request to the issue tracker: https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf/issues/new